# Criar abas dinamicamente no excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-excel

Estou realizando um projeto em MVC e gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de criar abas dinâmicas no Excel de acordo com filtros e exportá-lo posteriormente. 
Exemplo:
Caso o filtro venha apenas com "Escola" selecionado, ele cria apenas uma aba chamada Escola e exporta dados de escolas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso o filtro venha "Escola" e "Entidade" selecionados, ele cria duas abas chamadas Escola e Entidade e exportar os dados para cada um.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, existe. Montei o *Helper* abaixo que faz isso. Ele é baseado no pacote [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). Possivelmente você terá que alterar este *Helper* um pouco pra funcionar corretamente para o seu caso.

Note que ele usa bastante *Reflection*:

```
public static class ExcelHelper
{
    public static byte[] ExportarListaParaExcel<T>(IEnumerable<T> lista, String tituloPlanilha = "Exportação para Excel")
        where T: class, new()
    {
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Eu mesmo";
            excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Title = tituloPlanilha;
            var sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(tituloPlanilha);
            sheet.Name = tituloPlanilha;

            var properties = ReflectionUtils.ExtrairPropertiesDeObjeto(new T()).Where(p => !p.Name.EndsWith("Id") && !p.PropertyType.IsGenericType).ToList();
            var titulos = properties.Select(p => p.AtributoDisplayName() != null ? p.AtributoDisplayName().DisplayName : p.Name).ToArray();
            var i = 1;
            foreach (var titulo in titulos)
            {
                sheet.Cells[1, i++].Value = titulo;
            }

            var rowIndex = 2;
            foreach (var item in lista)
            {
                var col = 1;
                foreach (var prop in properties.Where(p => !p.Name.EndsWith("Id") && !p.PropertyType.IsGenericType))
                {
                    var val = item.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(item, null);
                    String str;

                    if (val == null)
                    {
                        str = "";
                    }
                    else if (val.GetType().IsPrimitive || val.GetType() == typeof(Decimal) || val.GetType() == typeof(String) || val.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        str = val.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        str = val.GetType().GetProperty("Nome").GetValue(val, null).ToString();
                    }
                    sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = str ?? "";
                }

                rowIndex++;
            }

            return excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] ExportarViewModelParaExcel(object viewModel, String tituloPlanilha = "Exportação para Excel")
    {
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Eu mesmo";
            excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Title = tituloPlanilha;

            foreach (var objeto in ReflectionUtils.ExtrairPropertiesDeObjeto(viewModel).ToList())
            {
                var sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(objeto.Name);
                sheet.Name = objeto.Name;

                if (objeto.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
                {
                    // É uma lista
                    var lista = (IEnumerable)objeto.GetValue(viewModel, null);
                    if (lista == null) continue;
                    var fields = lista.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    var titulos = fields.Select(p => p.AtributoDisplayName() != null ? p.AtributoDisplayName().DisplayName : p.Name).ToArray();
                    var i = 1;
                    foreach (var titulo in titulos)
                    {
                        sheet.Cells[1, i++].Value = titulo;
                    }

                    var rowIndex = 2;
                    foreach (var item in lista)
                    {
                        var col = 1;
                        foreach (var field in fields)
                        {
                            var val = item.GetType().GetField(field.Name).GetValue(item);
                            String str;

                            if (val == null)
                            {
                                str = "";
                            }
                            else if (val.GetType().IsPrimitive || val.GetType() == typeof(Decimal) || val.GetType() == typeof(String) || val.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                            {
                                str = val.ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                str = val.GetType().GetField("Nome").GetValue(val).ToString();
                            }
                            sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = str ?? "";
                        }

                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // É um objeto
                    var obj = objeto.GetValue(viewModel, null);
                    var fields = obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    var titulos = fields.Select(p => new {
                        Titulo = p.AtributoDisplayName() != null ? p.AtributoDisplayName().DisplayName : p.Name, 
                        Valor = p.GetValue(obj)
                    }).ToList();

                    var i = 1;
                    foreach (var titulo in titulos)
                    {
                        sheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = titulo.Titulo;
                        sheet.Cells[i++, 2].Value = titulo.Valor;
                    }
                }
            }

            return excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
        }
    }
}
```

O código que adiciona uma nova aba é este:

```
var sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(objeto.Name);
```

Para enviar para a *View*:

```
return File(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "Exemplo-" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xlsx");
```

A *Action* pode retornar `ActionResult` ou `FileResult`.

Comment: Consigo aplicar esse conceito usando DataTable para preencher cada aba do meu relatório?

Comment: Consegue. Só montar uma lista de `DataTable`s e adaptar o código.

Comment: Consegui montar direitinho. Só estou com dificuldade pra realizar o donwload do arquivo. Eu só consigo usar `wb.SaveAs(@"C:\Teste\Export.xlsx");` para baixar? Ou tem outras formas? @Cigano

Comment: @IgorMacedo Atualizei a resposta.